# Solve for length of vector so its sum with another vector has a given length

Tags: vectors

I'm trying to solve the following problem for a program I'm writing.

Assume I have two $2$-dimensional vectors in the $xy$-plane, and let's call them $\vec a$ and $\vec b$. The vector $\vec a$ is fixed and can be any length. The vector $\vec b$ is a unit vector, not parallel to $\vec a$.  Assume also that I have a scalar constant $k$.

How can I solve for $n$ such that $| \vec a + n \vec b | = k$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $\langle \vec{a},\vec{b}\rangle:= \vec{a}\circ \vec{b}=|\vec{a}| |\vec{b}|\cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ (so $0\leq \theta\leq \pi$). Note that $\langle \vec{a},\vec{a}\rangle=|\vec{a}|^2$.

Square both sides of $| \vec a + n \vec b | = k$ to get 
$$
| \vec a + n \vec b |^2 = |\vec{a}|^2 + n^2+2n|\vec{a}|\cos\theta = k^2, 
$$
where we use the fact that $|\vec{b}|=1$. 
Now, use the quadratic formula to solve for $n$ in: 
$$
n^2 + \left( 2|\vec{a}|\cos\theta\right) n + \left( |\vec{a}|^2 - k^2\right) = 0. 
$$
So 
$$
\begin{align*}
n &= \dfrac{-2|\vec{a}|\cos\theta\pm \sqrt{4|\vec{a}|^2\cos^2\theta -4(|\vec{a}|^2-k^2) }}{2} \\ 
&=\frac{-2|\vec{a}|\cos\theta \pm \sqrt{4k^2-4|\vec{a}|^2\sin^2\theta}}{2} \\ 
&= - |\vec{a}|\cos\theta \pm \sqrt{k^2 - |\vec{a}|^2\sin^2\theta}  \\  
&= - |\vec{a}|\cos\theta \pm \sqrt{(k - |\vec{a}|\sin\theta)(k + |\vec{a}|\sin\theta)}.  \\ 
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: The idea you used is really nice, professor.

Comment: Thank you professor.  You did an excellent job, in that your original answer was able to lead me to determining a form of the correct solution.  This was then confirmed as being correct after you had edited your solution.  I have now marked this as the solution.

Answer (score 3):

We need $k \geq 0$.

$$\langle a+nb, a+nb \rangle = k^2$$

$$|a|^2+2n\langle a, b \rangle + n^2=k^2$$

Hence you have to solve a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 1):

Mee Seong Im's original answer was close, and was enough to point me in the correct direction to solve this.  However with further testing I found that my suspicion in my comment above was correct, the original answer worked iff the two vectors are parallel.

Once I'd realized that this was going to be a quadratic solution, I started by separating each vector into its $x$ and $y$ components.  I have also renamed the vectors as $\vec p$ and $\vec q$ because in hindsight $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ were very poor choices on my part if a quadratic is involved, since by convention the coefficients of the quadratic equation are known as $a$, $b$ and $c$.

$\vec p$ is the fixed length vector: $(px, py)$, and $\vec q$ is the unit vector: $(qx, qy)$.

Writing this out fully I arrived at:

$(px + n qx) ^ 2 + (py + n qy) ^ 2 = k ^ 2$

which expands to:

$px^2 + 2n px qx + n^2 qx^2 + py ^ 2 + 2n py qy + n^2 qy^2 = k ^ 2$

Rearranging this gives the following:

$n^2 (qx^2 + qy^2) + 2 n (px qx + py qy) + (px^2 + qx^2 - k^2) = 0$

Setting up for a quadratic solve we get:

$a = (qx^2 + qy^2)$

$b = 2 (px qx + py qy)$

$c = px^2 + py^2 - k^2$

Since $\vec q$ is a unit vector, $a$ will always be $1$ at which point these can be plugged into the quadratic equation to get the necessary solutions.

-- Edit --

With the edit to Mee Seong Im's answer, i.e. the addition of the trig functions, it now matches this, albeit with a different way of expressing things.  e.g. where that answer has $|\vec p| \cos\theta$ , I have $(pxqx+pyqy)$ i.e. $\vec p . \vec q$ .  And of course, both of these are equivalent.

So I have marked that as the answer, even though all three current answers are correct.  Unfortunately, stack exchange does not all multiple answers to be selected.

Comment: This is [Siong Thye Goh’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361189/265466) expanded into coordinates, which is basically the same as [Mee Seong Im’s updated answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2361201/265466) without the extraneous trig functions.

Comment: @amd Indeed.  However my maths skills are no match for either Siong Thye Goh or Professor Mee Seong Im.  My brain just can't jump directly from that form of a solution to something that I can code.  Hence the reason I found it necessary to write this out one step at a time.

Comment: @amd Can't edit comments after 5 mins, so need to add another.  That said, it wasn't until Mee Seong Im noted that the $\langle p,q \rangle$ notation is a dot product that Siong Thye Goh's answer started making sense to.  And of course it is exactly what I wrote, just vastly more succinct.

Comment: +1 for working through it yourself given those hints.